# Open homebrew version of emacs instead of Apple version

Tags: bash, homebrew, emacs

I installed emacs 26.1 via `brew install emacs`, but when I try to start `emacs` via command line, only the outdated Apple-supplied version (22.1.1) opens.

However, emacs is apparently correctly linked:

```
$ which -a emacs
/usr/local/bin/emacs
/usr/bin/emacs

$ exa -l /usr/local/bin/emacs
lrwxr-xr-x 32 $USER 26 Aug 22:42 /usr/local/bin/emacs -> ../Cellar/emacs/26.1_1/bin/emacs

$ exa -l /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/26.1_1/bin/emacs
lrwxr-xr-x 10 $USER 25 May 18:41 /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/26.1_1/bin/emacs -> emacs-26.1
```

`PATH` also has `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, so why does `emacs` still open `/usr/bin/emacs`?

Comment: Are there any aliases?  Run `alias` to find out.  A function could also cause this and wouldn't be noticed by `which`.  Run `set` to see if any functions are defined.

Comment: Check the output of `type -a emacs`

Comment: @chicks There are no aliases and `set | grep 'emacs'` only returns `SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor`

@NimeshNeema `type -a emacs` yields `emacs is /usr/local/bin/emacs`
`emacs is /usr/bin/emacs`

Comment: @NimeshNeema I logged out and back in again in before I ran the command, so it already shows the correct path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that `emacs` was still hashed, so the old version was used even after installing the new one.
Therefore,

```
$ type emacs
emacs is hashed (/usr/bin/emacs)
```

This can be remedied by either logging out and then back in again, or forcing the shell to rehash by running [`hash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-hash)`emacs`, which will result in

```
$ type emacs
emacs is hashed (/usr/local/bin/emacs)
```

Then, the correct version will be used.